# qTip2 - all html content disaper on adding css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use qtip2 but while adding the css to page all the content of page disappear..

need help if i am doing some thing wrong..

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qtip.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <style type="text/css" href="jquery.qtip.css"/> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://qtip2.com/v/nightly/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" href="http://qtip2.com/v/nightly/jquery.qtip.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip[id^="tooltip_"]').each(function(){
            $(this).qtip({
                content: $(this).find('span.tooltip'),
                hide: {
                    fixed: true,
                    delay: 180
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="tooltip_1" href="#" class="tooltip" >Trigger1<span class="tooltip" style="display: none;">data_tooltip_1: You can hover over and interacte with me</span></a><li>
        <li><a id="tooltip_2" href="#" class="tooltip" >Trigger2<span class="tooltip" style="display: none;">data_tooltip_2: You can hover over and interacte with me</span></a><li>
        <li><a id="tooltip_3" href="#" class="tooltip" >Trigger3<span class="tooltip" style="display: none;">data_tooltip_3: You can hover over and interacte with me</span></a><li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<style>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) is used only for specifying CSS inside HTML document itself, but not for referencing external CSS file like you can do with `<script>` for JavaScript, so all content of your page is being threated as a stylesheet. What you need is [`<link>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://qtip2.com/v/nightly/jquery.qtip.css" />
```